# Python Localhost refuses connection

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code for a port scanner is as follows:

```
    import socket as sk

    for port in range(1, 1024):
        try:
            s = sk.socket(sk.AF_INET,sk.SOCK_STREAM)
            s.settimeout(1000)
            s.connect(("127.0.0.1",port))
            print("{0}:OPEN".format(port))
            s.close
        except: continue
```

I get this error:

```
    s.connect(("127.0.0.1",port))
    ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made 
    because the target machine actively refused it
```

Why is this??

Comment: This happens because you don't have all of the ports from 1 to 1023 open and therefor no connection can be made. You have to handle the exception.

Comment: I try it in my windows, no error with really long time. So just print `port` before `connect`, check which port produce this error. Then you can dig more.

Comment: Added an exception and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Klaus D. pointed me in the right direction. I had to create a try/except statement around the line creating the error, allowing me to continue. This happened because a closed port created an error, ending the program. The exception allowed me to continue checking ports after each error.